# Cordova plugin call log not install in my ionic app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

my system configuration is
npm- 3.10.10
ionic- 3.4.0
cordova - 7.0.1
node - 6.11.0

i used this plugin-
cordova plugins add "https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin"

Comment: It's hard to understand what your actual problem is, can you give more details?

Comment: please tell me if anyone have solution for that